# Print scientific variable on txt file using f.write()

Tags: python

Since a couple of hours, I am trying to print a simple time vector in a txt file using Python.

```
import numpy as np 

Tp = 2000 * 10**(-9) 
dt = Tp / (90000)

t = np.linspace(0,Tp,dt)

timing = open("time.txt","w")

for ii in range(len(t)) : 
   timing.write(str(t[ii]))
   timing.write("\n")

timing.close()
```

But I still get an empty file and I don't understand at all why.
Maybe I have to be more specific in the function with the precision I want.

Since I have a lot of small numbers (4e-10 ..) to process I would like to understand a general method to write variable (not the entire vector at once) on a txt file with a exponential notation (In Matlab it's kind of automatic I think). 
Thx

Comment: `t` is empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error using linspace. Please check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Try this:

```
import numpy as np 


Tp = 2000 * 10**(-9) 
# dt = Tp / 90000.0
dt = 90000

t = np.linspace(0,Tp,dt)

timing = open("time.txt","w")

for ii in range(len(t)) : 
   timing.write(str(t[ii]))
   timing.write("\n")

timing.close()
```